# Mysql error 1045 - access denied for 'db_user'@'@localhost' (with two at symbols @)

Tags: php, mysql, windows, phpmyadmin, wamp

I installed WAMP (last version: 3.0.6) on a new PC. I extracted a database from my old PC and imported it through phpMyAdmin. I created a user ('db_user'@'%') with all the rights to access this database (every rights on everything, indeed).

When I connect to phpMyAdmin with this user it works but when I try to connect through a web-interface using PHP, I get the following error message:

> 1045 - access denied for 'db_user'@'@localhost')

My connector PHP file looks like this:

```
define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "db_user");
define("PASSWORD", "a_password");
define("DATABASE", "my_test_db");
define("CAN_REGISTER", "any");
define("DEFAULT_ROLE", "member");

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

The same thing was working on my old computer.
What can I do?

Comment: Would you try connecting via the command line as follows, "mysql -h localhost -u db_user -pa_password"    ; and see what happens? If you are on windows you might have to go to the mysql folder to have the mysql command recognized. I want to know where the '@' sign gets added to 'localhost'

Comment: Thanks, the '@' is already there when I write it into the command line.

Comment: _Small note_ Last version is currently `WAMPServer3.0.9`

Comment: Try to see the users and their hosts in your database. "SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user". See if you have a host that start with '@', which shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "db_user");
define("PASSWORD", "a_password");
define("DATABASE", "my_test_db");
define("CAN_REGISTER", "any");
define("DEFAULT_ROLE", "member");

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

try {
     $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
     $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
} catch (Exception $e ) {
     echo "Service unavailable";
     echo "message: " . $e->message;   // not in live code obviously...
     exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I still got the same error (nothing more). I think it is due to those two at symbols ( 'db_user'@'@localhost'). But, I don't know why is mysql adding another @ before localhost? (and I don't know how to get rid of it).

Comment: remove line $mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); and try

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't change anything.